# Creating a form in Rails: What method needs to be passed to the various inputs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I'm trying to put together a form in Rails using form_for.

```
<%= form_for([current_user, @quiz_answer]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.check_box <WHAT PARAMETERS HERE?> %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit("Get my results!") %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

I've checked the API page for FormBuilder here:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-check_box
and it says that each of the methods takes a method as its first parameter. What should that method be, and where would it come from, usually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument to `check_box` is the field of the related attribute on the model.  So in your case, the model for the form is a `QuizAnswer`, so let's say it had an attribute of `selected`, maybe.  In that case, the logic would be...

```
<%= f.check_box :selected %>
```

Comment: OK - thanks for this. I guess the next step is figuring out how to display the quiz questions and hook them up to the right QuizAnswer.